# Is google analytics custom variable a good way to segment different parts of a very large site?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

Is google analytics custom variable a good way to segment different parts of a very large site? Currently they are just segmented and filtered by title tag but we'd like to get both a specific look at what pages are viewed in segments as well as the overall health of each segment. I've seen where it says that google custom variables can be overwritten, is this going to cause a problem for getting accurate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom variables for segmentation (that's what they are for), but in standard GA there are only five customs vars in three different scopes (page, session, visitor) and variables in different scopes but the same "slot" might interfere with each other. So using custom vars requires more thought and more testing than one would think (especially since you will get results in any case, so you need good tests to separate data from noise).

So you might want to investigate some of the more straightforward options first - if your site is strictly hierachical you might be able to use the url scheme, or something like that, this should do anything that can be achieved by page scope custom vars.

If you want to segment by user behaviour during a visit, or multiple recurring visits, you'll have to use session- and visitor scope custom variables. If at all possible do not re-use different "slots" (custom vars are numbered from 1 to 5) in different scopes.

Comment: can I use the same variable on different sections with different values and filter by that variable and still have accurate results?

Comment: You shoud be.... the only real guidance I could find is offered by Google itself in the docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#usage. After reading that I decided to be careful and not reuse variables (however since there are only five slots this might not be feasible for you)